# How to apply a PropertyChanges on a property named "target"

Tags: qml

Here's an example `State` and `PropertyChanges` from the docs:

```
State {
    name: "resized"; when: mouseArea.pressed
    PropertyChanges { target: rect; color: "blue"; height: container.height }
}
```

The object to change is identified in the `target` property, and other properties of `PropertyChanges` map 1-to-1 to properties of the targeted object.

But if one wants to change a property named `target` on `foo` to `bar`, the naive thing would be `PropertyChanges { target: foo; target: bar }`, which I'm sure wouldn't work.

Is there a way to disambiguate the target of `PropertyChanges` from the target of its target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little tweak, this is no problem.
If you can't alias it at the targetobject creation yourself, do it in the states like so:

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    property int target: 20
    x: target
    y: target
    width: target
    height: target
    color: 'orchid'

    states: State {
        id: altState
        name: 'alternative'
        property alias mytarget: rect.target
        PropertyChanges {
            target: altState
            mytarget: 50
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: parent.state = 'alternative'

    }
}
```